# Why do I have to specify generic type when it is used as a member or variable

Tags: typescript, oop, generics, abstract, typescript-generics

I have the following class as an example:

```
export abstract class AbstractSomething<T extends SomethingElse, V> { }
```

I also have the following 2 extending classes:

```
export class A extends AbstractSomething<TypeThatExtendsSomethingElse, string> { }
export class B extends AbstractSomething<OtherTypeThatExtendsSomethingElse, boolean> { }
```

Now in a third unrelated `ServiceClass` class I have a member that is an array of `AbstractSomething` (each item in the array could be either A or B):

```
export class ServiceClass {
    public array: AbstractSomething[];
}
```

The above code gives the following error: `Generic type 'AbstractSomething' requires 2 type arguments`.

I'm trying to figure out why do I get this error? The above code works fine in Java. My member could be of any generic type, not just a specific one. I could maybe make the array type `AbstractSomething<any, any>[]` but that would not be correct as the first generic type extends `SomethingElse`.

Why do I get this error and what would be a possible solution?

Comment: Why not `public array: Array<A|B>;` instead, if that's what you're going to use?  Also, are you *sure* that "the above code works fine in Java" is true?  To my recollection, if you've got a generic class in Java you need to specify the type parameter(s) whenever you refer to it.  You might be able to do `AbstractSomething<?,?>` in Java, but you can't write `AbstractSomething`.

Comment: I have tested it in Java with a List and I'm positive it works. I'm not going for A|B because in reality I have way more than 2 extending classes and honestly its just an uglier solution.

Comment: Oh, right... Java does allow unspecified generics (aka "raw" types) in order to be backwards compatible with Java 1.4. But the compiler definitely complains about it, right?

Comment: It's a compiler warning, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you should explicitly pass generic arguments, but instead of `any` it could be `AbstractSomething<SomethingElse, unknown>`. In this case you tell the compiler that the first type is `SomethingElse` or any of it descendants, and the second type is unknown. `unknown` type is safer that `any`, see the [difference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type).

You can also assign default values to generic types, in this case you can skip the types and default ones will be used, like:

```js
export class AbstractSomething<T extends SomethingElse = SomethingElse, V = unknown> { }
const arr: AbstractSomething[] = [];
```

If the array may contain only `A` or `B` items, it would be better to define it as `Array<A | B>`, this type is more verbose, you can use it like:

```js
const arr = new Array<A | B>();
...
const item = arr[0];
if (item instanceof A) {
  // do something with A
} else {
  // the compiler knows that the item has B type
}
```

Comment: Note that `AbstractSomething<SomethingElse, unknown>` will only work if the actual `AbstractSomething<T, V>` is [covariant](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) in `T` and `V`.  Otherwise this will fail.  Of course the example code leaves `T` and `V` completely unused, which leads to [strange behavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--), so it's hard to know.

Comment: That's definitely an acceptable solution, thank you very much :)